# How do I find the output of the following code fragment in Java?

Tags: java, loops, iteration

I have the following code fragment, which yields a sum of 16.

```
int sum = 1;
for (int i = 0; i <= 5; sum = sum + i++)
System.out.println(sum);
```

From my understanding of sum = sum + i++ and for loops in general, my thought process for the loop would be like this:

- 0th loop: sum = 1 (do nothing)
- 1st loop: sum = 1 + 1 (uses sum = 1 from previous iteration )
- 2nd loop: sum = 2 + 2
- 3rd loop: sum = 4 + 3
- 4th loop: sum = 7 + 4
- 5th loop: sum = 11 + 5

Obviously, there is an error in my logic. Could you please explain why the sum would be 16?

Comment: I don't understand. You gave your thought process and said that you expect the final iteration of the loop to do `sum = 11 + 5`. You state that you ran the code and got a result of `16`. You seem to be *surprised* by this result. Do you expect `11 + 5` to result in something other than `16`? Why? The way you've titled the question also doesn't make sense - obviously you find out what code does by running it.

Answer (score 2):

Change `System.out.println(sum);` to include the loop number as well. Also, don't forget to print the values **after** your loop.

```
int sum = 1;
for (int i = 0; i <= 5; sum = sum + i++) {
    System.out.printf("loop=%d, sum=%d%n", i, sum);
}
System.out.printf("after loop, sum=%d%n", sum);
```

Output

```
loop=0, sum=1
loop=1, sum=1
loop=2, sum=2
loop=3, sum=4
loop=4, sum=7
loop=5, sum=11
after loop, sum=16
```

Which I trust explains both *how* and *why* `sum` is `16` after the loop.